# Get Azure VM's NSG Using Powershell CLI

Tags: azure, powershell

The task is to modify an Azure Network Security Group Rule.

I am all OK there (using az network nsg rule update ), provided the name of the NSG and the actual Rule.

But what I want to do is edit that rule with the VM Name (subscription ID, RG name and Rule name are already known and will be explicit) as the input parameter.

I am using az (not Az) commands.

What I see is az vm show, but it doesn't show which NSG the VM is connected to.

I would like to ask how to get the NSG name where a VM is associated, using CLI. Straight answers, guides or links to resources will all be appreciated.

Thank you and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would also need to provide the Resource Group in which the VM is located - this is how it will be able to differentiate between two VM with same name in different Resource Groups. Here, `{id:id}` creates a map that can be used with the subsequent commands. There are other ways to do this but I prefer this approach since I'm more familiar with the format.

Here's what you could do:

1. Using the VM name and RG, get the VM's NIC's ID and save it to `nic_id`:

```
vm_name="myvm"
vm_rg="myrg"
nic_id=`az vm nic list -g $vm_rg --vm-name $vm_name --query "[].{id:id}"`
# echo to make sure we're getting the right value. 
echo $nic_id
```

2. Using the NIC ID, get the Subnet ID

```
snet_id=`az network nic show --ids $nic_id --query "ipConfigurations[0].subnet.{id:id}"`
# echo to make sure we're getting the right value. 
echo $snet_id
```

3. Finally, using the Subnet ID, get the NSG's name

```
nsg_name=`az network vnet subnet show --ids $snet_id --query networkSecurityGroup.{id:id} -o tsv | sed 's/^.*networkSecurityGroups\///'`
# echo to make sure we're getting the right value. 
echo $nsg_name
```

Comment: This looks awesome. Already on the road though, but reading from this I do have some questions
1. What does the tsv value mean?
2. also this part --query "ipConfigurations[0].subnet.{id:id}"

Will update as soon as I try this

Comment: `tsv` is tab-separated values, `-o` is for output. This ensures the output is not enclosed within double quotes. As for this `--query "ipConfigurations[0].subnet.{id:id}"`, these are keys in the json object, each NIC can have multiple ipConfigurations, here I'm assuming that you only have one and I'm getting the IPConfig at index 0 (the first one), then it's subnet, and the id of the subnet. This is how you would retrieve values from keys in a json formatted object.

Refer to this for a good explanation about az cli JMESPath: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/query-azure-cli

Comment: got it. now I'm on the string parsing thing as the id being extracted looks like a path and the id itself is after the last / .

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Microsoft documentation below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworksecuritygroup?view=azps-6.5.0

```
Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup [-Name <String>][-ResourceGroupName<String> [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>][<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this but I am using the az cli and not Az. I can get and update the NSG details fine, but this is if I already know the NSG and Rule names. The challenge for me is that the input will be just the VM name.
My plan is,
1. Create a VM object using VM Name
2. Get the VM's NIC and determine what NSG it is attached to
3. Update the NSG rule

I am stuck at step 1. :)